# Define a new command in a `declarative way"

Tags: macros

There are commands that look like pressing a button in MS Word(I have Windows...). For example `\textbf{small bold text}` compared with `{\bf  lengthly bold text }` My question is : Is it posible to define a new command in a declarative way like `\bf` or redifine an old one in this style?

Comment: Note: `\bf` is deprecated, the current command is `\bfseries`.

Comment: Also, it's better to avoid redefining an existing command unless you know what you're doing (and in some cases, it's not even possible).

Comment: Which button is that in Word?

Comment: As `\bf` (or the better `\bfseries`) is defined as you want it, it is obviously possible. But it is rather unclear what exactly you want to achieve,

Comment: Do you really want a command which does what `\bf` used to do i.e. switches to bold, upright even if the current text is using the italic shape? `\bfseries` would keep the italic and just change the weight. Is that not what you want?

Comment: It is not clear at all what you mean by "declarative". Do you just mean that changes some setting in the current scope instead of applying to an argument? If so it can only work for commands that change typesetting parameters...

Comment: The suggested form ` \textbf{....}` is more readable, harder to mistype. Your gentle readers know them. Don't go out of your way to make life harder all around.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I could need such a `\bf`. I have **never** understood the _deprecated_ story, I lament that the "is deprecated admonition" is copied  around zillions of times by people (in a similar way as "never never use dollar signs for maths"), and I regret the recent decisions in Koma-script to harass the users who want to use `\bf`.

Comment: @jfbu It does not behave as people expect and it does not make appropriate corrections. Using double-dollar signs for display maths is similarly not good. Using single-dollars for inline maths is fine because it is as good as the newer syntax. There are good reasons for these admonitions. If you *really* need something which will switch to a fixed font, you can do it. But that is not what 'bold' means to most people so it is better not to have the 'bold' command behave that way.

Comment: @cfr I am not in disagreement at all (except for `$$ vs \[` the latter being seriously buggy in legacy `LaTeX2e`, corrected by `amsmath`). However the decision of `LaTeX` authors to maintain macros while saying they are _deprecated_ is disputable. Either remove them, or change their meanings if really the old behavior was so disastrous, but don't let thousands of users repeat as an incantation "deprecated" when in fact I will not hurt physically my computer using them, and might very well actually need them and not `\bfseries`. (*continued*)

Comment: @cfr a better policy could have been to tell users: you want to use `\bf`? ok, then load `LaTeX2e` with a `compat=usebaddeprecatedbfbecauseIwantit`. And without this key or option, no more any `\bf`. That would spare many people sheepishly reproduce an advice whose groundings they not always understand as expertly as you do.

Comment: @jfbu Even setting aside concerns about backwards compatibility - which is taken extremely seriously - removing or changing the meaning of ***TeX*** commands is hardly a policy to be recommended. Be careful what you wish for.

Comment: @cfr The meaning of `\bf` obviously is already changed by **_LaTeX_** (compare `latexdef bf` with `texdef bf`). I wish for a working command `\@fontswitch {\normalfont \bfseries }{\mathbf }` not to be said _deprecated_, and forums and sites like this one containing thousands of well-wishing reminders about it by people who are not as well informed as you are. Try posting a MWE using `\bf` and immediately you will see comments about not using `\bf` whether or not it has any relation with the problem at hand. In my own packages, I sometimes declare _deprecated_ some things (_continued_)

Comment: @cfr I try for this to happen very rarely, but once it is done, at some point I will simply remove the _deprecated_  macros entirely. People having been warned enough.

Comment: @cfr reading my comments I see I wrote _decision of LaTeX authors to maintain macros while saying they are deprecated_ which I want to retract because possibly no-one from the LaTeX team said `\bf` to be _deprecated_, hence my blaming was hastily pronounced. `fntguide` has no such thing it seems, I can't afford buying the `LaTeX companion`. With `KOMA`: ``Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of deprecated font command `\bf'!`` But ends with ``KOMA-Script will remove the definition of `\bf' anytime until release of about version 3.20`` which is ok. Strange, I thought recent **_KOMA_** issued an error.

Comment: @cfr `classes.pdf` contains ``These commands work in text mode and in math mode. They are provided for compatibility, but one should start using the \text... and \math... commands instead.``, very reasonable. No _deprecated_ there. Hence I don't know who is to """blame""" for the _deprecated_ story, and even more, I see that according to the official sources there is _nothing_ """deprecated""" about `\bf` or other such commands.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, you simply need not to define arguments. Although different methods might be in order depending on the command. For the sake of the question, here's a command that turns the text **bold** and *italics*, together.

Note the `{}` around the command and the text. Without those, the bold and italics will continue until the document ends.

Also, `\bf` is deprecated. In new Latex documents, you must use `\bfseries`.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\bfandit{%
    \itshape\bfseries%
}

\begin{document}

Text as it should be.\medskip

{\bfandit No, wait, not bold and italics together!}\medskip

Ok, now it's better.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not end lines with `\\ ` except in special contexts such as tabulars, arrays etc. Don't you get bad boxes with this? (I do.)

Comment: @HoodChatham But that is not true. Did you try it? You will get `some textmore text` just as you should because the macro will gobble the following space as it usually does. I don't know why you would need a comment sign there - I would not have thought you did. (Although it does no harm.)

Comment: Alenanno Thanks for the answer! Both \bfseries and \itshapes are declarative so is their combination. My question is very general. I would like to write {\url http://google.com} instead of  \url{http://google.com} etc. My opinion is that if a command use a lengtly argument then is better to be defined in declerative way. So my question is : How one could define such commands ?

Comment: @kornaros You must know, what settings you need to achieve the desired behavior at TeX primitive level. These settings must be local. Then the definition is simple: `\def\url{appropriate settings}`.

Comment: @cfr Yes, it was just to artificially create new lines. Although it irritates me that even though I leave an empty line in the editor, Latex ignores it. >_>

Comment: @kornaros Do you mean like `{\url <link>}`? Or like `text... \url <link> \endurl ...text again`?

Comment: @cfr No, clearly I didn't test it. My guess is that no space appears because `\it` ends in `\ignorespaces`. If I say `\def\donothing{<new line>}` then `a\donothing b` produces "a b". On the other hand, with `\def\donothing{\ignorespaces<new line>}`, `a\donothing b` produces "ab", so I assume that's what's going on.

Comment: @Alenanno That is a bad way to break lines. LaTeX does not ignore empty lines in the source `.tex` unless you have done something odd. The only other thing I can think is that your editor makes what looks like a blank line but which is not really one.  In that case, you should definitely find a better editor. You will have bad boxes when you break lines in that way.

Comment: @HoodChatham It is a space following a macro which gets eaten. That doesn't mean that spaces within the macro get eaten. So if you define a macro to include a space, using the macro will produce that space. Try `\def\donothing{} a b a\donothing b \def\dosomething{ c} a\dosomething b`. You don't need `\ignorespaces` for the macro to gobble a following space. (And a new line is just a space, of course.)

Comment: @cfr Oh I usually have those in examples when I want to separate the lines. I don't usually have them in my documents. :D I have them only in two glosses, but if I remove them there, I get errors. So while I'm trying to find a way to fix those, I'll keep those there.

Comment: @cfr Okay, that makes sense. I thought that a newline would generate a space even if it immediately followed a command. I think this is the result of looking at various existing packages -- tikz.code.tex for instance has thousands of lines that end in commands, all of which are followed by a `%`. After a while I started to believe those `%`'s did something. Thanks for correcting that misunderstanding!

Comment: @HoodChatham TikZ parses stuff differently than TeX, as I understand it. I believe it essentially involves its own parser. So the comment signs may be doing something *there* because *there* is being TikZ-parsed rather than (directly) TeX-parsed, if you see what I mean. Also *some* commands don't eat spaces, but they are exceptions generally rather than rules. (I don't think single character macros generally eat space, for example. E.g. `\&` etc.)

Comment: @cfr Yeah, in the TeXbook, Knuth discusses the distinction between a "control symbol" like `\&` and a "control word" like `\mymacro`. A space after a control word delimits the end of the macro. No such delimiting space is needed after a control symbol, so that space isn't eaten. I'm pretty confident that most of the `%`'s in the tikz code don't matter. Tikz doesn't change the catcode of space and the font is set to nullfont. As you point out, if they use some control word as a delimiter rather than a macro, spaces after it would be respected, but this is only rarely the case.

Comment: @HoodChatham I don't know the TikZ code. But I understand that it uses spaces in ways which are different and important. This is why TikZ is fundamentally incompatible with the l3 syntax, for example. But, as I say, I don't know whether the comments in the code are needed or not. In any case, they do no harm, and it is better to include unnecessary comments than miss necessary ones, so including them is not a bad precautionary principle ;).

Comment: @Alenanno I don't know how \bfseries is defined.But looks like pressing a button. Everything in its right is bold. I would like to see how one could define a command in this way. Then I could define new functions like \red, \underline \overline etc. and write simply \red \underline a textWithManyLines instead \red{\underline{ text...}} That is my question!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have some command `\mycommand{...}` and you insist on using a syntax `{\mybutton ...}` rather. You can try this. Will not always work (for example for verbatim-like commands). The outer braces are **mandatory**, and `\foo{\mybutton ...}` will not work, use `\foo{{\mybutton...}}` (and keep fingers crossed.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mybf {\iftrue\expandafter\mybf@\expandafter{\else}\fi}
\newcommand\mybf@ [1]{\textbf{{#1}}\egroup}

\newcommand\myunderline {\iftrue\expandafter\myunderline@\expandafter{\else}\fi}
\newcommand\myunderline@ [1]{\underline{{#1}}\egroup}

\newcommand\myred  {\iftrue\expandafter\myred@\expandafter{\else}\fi}
\newcommand\myred@ [1]{\textcolor{red}{{#1}}\egroup}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\myunderline Hello Beautiful} World

{\mybf Hello Beautiful} World

{\mybf\myunderline Hello Beautiful} World

{\mybf\myunderline\myred Hello Beautiful} World

{\myred\myunderline\mybf Hello Beautiful} World

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ManYY Thanks! This is what I was looking for!  A question: Why \bfseries works qood even without braces(like pressing a button)? You just write \bfseries and everhing after that is  bold! What is the mechanism behind? Another question: What do you mean by verbatim-like commands?

Comment: At its innermost core, `TeX` has primitives to handle fonts. `\bfseries` is a `LaTeX` command, which, in combination with many other user-hidden `LaTeX` commands tells to switch font, keeping most characterstics apart from using bold face. For more, you can type `texdoc fntguide` for a start. My answer is only a hack to convert generically some commands with one argument `\foo{...}` into the form `{\foo ...}`. This will not work in all contexts.

Comment: There is a notion of "catcode" in TeX which you probably don't want to hear more about. Suffice it to say that some macros rely on changing catcodes and if you grab the argument too early it will then be too late. LaTeX has the command `\verb` which does that. Admittedly its syntax is `\verb|..|` or `\verb+..+` or whatever in place of `|` and `+`,  thus does not really fall into the set-up of my answer.

Comment: If I understand well, you say that it is impossible to define a function like \bfseries (i.e. \foo text ...) without any need for  brackets ? For example something like  \redtext.....\blacktext ....(no need of { and } like pressing a button...)